# missing cell on tableView visibleCells swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4

When I get visible cells in my tableView after scrolling to second row in tableView its give me one cell missing there is 8 cells and its give me 7 cells here is my code

```
if response.count > 1
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: false)
    }
    if let _ = self.tableView {
        let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells
        UIView.animate(views: cells, animations: [], reversed: false, initialAlpha: 0, finalAlpha: 1, delay: 0, animationInterval: 0.1, duration: ViewAnimatorConfig.duration, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Most likely, because you're not waiting for the table view to actually scroll to row 1, `self.tableView.visibleCells` is returning rows 0 through 7.

Comment: How could I wait scroll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the "ViewAnimator" that it appears you are using, so I can't test it, but this *should* work for you:

```
    if response.count > 1 {

        let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: false)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
            _ in

            let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells

            // un-comment to output the array of visible cells
            // to debug console to confirm the desired rows are visible
            //print(cells)

            UIView.animate(views: cells, animations: [], reversed: false, initialAlpha: 0, finalAlpha: 1, delay: 0, animationInterval: 0.1, duration: ViewAnimatorConfig.duration, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.allowAnimatedContent, completion: nil)
        })

    }
```